# Openlayers WMS layer comes up blank until I zoom in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openlayers, geoserver

I'm trying to integrate Openlayers with ASP MVC3 using Geoserver as a learning process but came across this weird problem.  When I load the view, the map canvas comes up blank with the default zoom control. Only when I press the zoom-in button the map would display.  I originally thought it's something to do with ASP's Razor View so I copy it to a separate HTML file but the problem remains.  Any suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function init() {
        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    -124.848974, 45.543541,
                    -116.91558, 49.002494);
        var options = {
            maxExtent: bounds,
            maxResolution: 0.0309898203125,
            projection: "EPSG:4326",
            units: 'degrees'
        };
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Washington County Map", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms",
            {
                layers: 'tiger:county10',
                format: 'image/png',
                visibility: true,
                isBaseLayer: true,
            });

        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToExtend(bounds);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body  onload="init()">
<h2>Test</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

<div id="map" style="width:800px; height:500px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In such cases, it's useful to get URL of WMS query (from Firebug, Chrome's Console etc) and execute it directly in browser. It may give information, why query failes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Geoserver settings for zoom levels? You can set the min and max scales where to display each map layer.